# Calculate total with price and quantity using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using `ui.bootstrap.typeahead`, I select a product from my json list (by typing 'P'). My goal is to set the total price automatically. But I can't get the price of the selected product to display (`value="{{selected.price}}"`) so it can calculate the total. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/F9jPt7IZgsWyON2vEmic

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap.productautocomplete"]);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="ProductAutocompleteCtrl">

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input id="product_info" name="product_info" ng-change="displayPrice()" type="text" placeholder="Autocomplete - Type 'P' to find product's name" ng-model="selected" typeahead="product as product.name for product in products | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"
      autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input id="price" name="price"  ng-model="prc"  ng-validate="number" placeholder="Autocomplete - Price" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{selected.price}}">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input id="quantity" name="quantity" ng-model="qty" ng-change="changePrice()" ng-validate="integer" placeholder="Quantity" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input id="total_prod1" name="total_prod1" ng-model="totalprod" ng-validate="number" placeholder="Total price" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>

  </div> <!-- ng-controller -->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

products.json

```
{"products":[
{"productversion":1,"name":"product1","price":"10.00"},
{"productversion":2,"name":"product2","price":"20.00"}
]}
```

script.js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.productautocomplete', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.productautocomplete').controller('ProductAutocompleteCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;

  var urlapiproducts = "products.json" ;
    //console.log(urlapiproducts);

    $http.get(urlapiproducts).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.products = data.products;  


    // console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("No data found..");
  });


    $scope.displayPrice = function(){
        var qty = 0;        
        var prc = 0;        

        qty = 1;
        prc = $scope.prc;    

        $scope.qty = qty;        

        $scope.totalprod = qty * prc;  
    }  

    $scope.changePrice = function(){
        var qty = 0;
        var prc = 0;

        qty = $scope.qty;       
        prc = $scope.prc;

        if(qty > 0 && prc > 0)
        {
            $scope.totalprod = qty * prc;
        }          
    }  

}]);
```

**update #1**

ng-model was changed from `prc` to `selected.price`

```
<input id="price" name="price" ng-model="selected.price"  ng-validate="number" type="text" value="{{selected.price}}">
```

This displays price and initial (1) quantity properly. Thanks @AbdelrhmanMohamed

Now the issue is that I'm not sure how to use the `selected.price` value to calculate total price (price * quantity). When product is selected, price is displayed, but `selected.price` is still undefined in displayPrice()

**update #2**

Problem: ng-change not firing when ng-model is changed

Solved by using `$scope.$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('selected.price', function() {
  $scope.displayPrice();
});
```

Comment: You need to make `ng-model="selected.price"` for the price controll,=

Comment: Thanks, how can I use the value of `selected.price` in the displayPrice function? `$scope.selected.price;`  doesn't seem to work (undefined).

Comment: check this link http://plnkr.co/edit/du617prbRPOYBrqx5sYF?p=preview I modified the html and the controller

Comment: Super, it works, except for the total price. In the `displayPrice function`, should `selected.price` be reference as  `$scope.selected.price;`  inside the function?

Comment: If I add `ng-change="changePrice()"`  to price, so it calculates the total price as soon as a product is selected, it doesn't work.. actually, it crashed Firefox when I tested this in Plunker

Comment: you could to use $broadcast and $on to inform any change on selections, and calculate the total using a loop on javascript. currently, the variable for total never is setted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to **leave out  the $watch()** function, you dont need it as all the bindings work ok.

### first of all change ng-change to typeahead-on-select

Since ng-change is executed on each keydown event, we dont need it until we select an actual value from the list. Instead of `ng-change` you can use `typeahead-on-select`, which is executed as soon as a value is selected.

**your typeahead directive:**

```
 <input id="product_info" name="product_info" typeahead-on-select="displayPrice(product)" type="text" 
                      placeholder="Autocomplete - Type 'P' to find product's name" ng-model="product"
                      typeahead="product as product.name for product in products | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
                      class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

apart from that there is not a major change on the code just minor changes: 
take a look on the live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/R3LON9?p=preview

Hope this helps, good luck.